# How to render this

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

I downloaded an obj+mtl from Betanji (on the left image) and tried to render it on cycles (on the right image). What I supposed to do to get the same render as on the Betanji site??

[image]

Comment: Hello, you need to work on the materials and on the lights I guess, your question is probably a little bit too broad

Comment: I used a hdri as image texture for world light. And I thought that the mtl file control all the material things well (color, roughness, transparency...) but it does not even familiar with the showed image:( Anyway, thanks for your answer, Im trying to fix it;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using an HDRI, the lighting for those kinds of scenes are usually done (in cycles) by placing a (relatively) large plane nearby at an angle and giving it an emission texture (to simulate studio "lamps"). From your image, it looks like all you have for lighting (besides the HDRI) is the default "point light", embedded in the center of your scene (between the bottle and the jar). I could be wrong, though - its hard to tell from the image. Also, make sure to connect the alpha outputs from your images with transparency to the alpha input of their respective Principled BSDF's (that could be responsible for the black blotches in your glass objects).

[image: EmitPlane]

Comment: Thank you very much! You were right, the materials were unaccurate and nods were plugged badly, I also put up large area light which helped a lot. Thans again @christopher bennet and moonboots